# Positioning a div in grid 960 is adding mystery padding / margin

Tags: html, css, html5boilerplate

*Browsers tested in:  Chrome, IE, Firefox.
Problem is that BusinessNav ID keeps getting pushed over 3 columns.*

Here's what I want the page to look like http://www.designobvio.us/dov2/Homepage1.pdf

I definably can hack this code to make the positioning work.  But as you can see theres still so much more page left.  If I start hacking now it's definably going to get progressively more ugly.

First here's the site: http://designobvio.us/dov2/index.html 
(I've highlighted potential problem areas)

CSS styles: search /**User Styles **/ (there are only a few)

heres the low down:

```
  <div id="businessNav" class="grid_3 ">
   <h2>Relationship</h2>
   <h2>Wages</h2>
   <h2>Common Sense</h2>
   <h2>Forward Thinker</h2>
   <h2>Learning</h2>
  </div>
```

this chunk of code is being afflicted by:

```
  <div id="heresWhy" class="grid_3">
   <h1>And Here's Why</h1>
   <p>...<p> 
  </div>
```

Or

```
<div id="headerBusiness" class="grid_6">
  <h1>Business</h1>
</div>
```

Anyone see the discrepancy in my code?
Thanks everyone

Comment: Can you please explain what your actual problem is? Where is the padding you are seeing? What browser are you in?

Comment: yes no problem:Browser = chrome, ie, ff. and the #businessNav is where the error is occuring

Comment: If you look at the picture in the first link you'll see that the #businessNav is right below #heresWhy.  However in my code it keep getting pushed over 3 columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because height of "Hereswhy" is 362px, while your "headerBusiness" is just 360px,  so your "BusinessNav" cannot float to the left.

once you give "Hereswhy" and "headerBusiness" the same height, like 362px, it would give u what you want

Comment: god they looked virtually the same! Ugh I will learn from this mistake! Thank you so much.